# Scala applying implicit functions to a collection

Tags: scala, collections, implicit

EDIT: I'm using Scala 2.9.2

In Scala, I've defined a custom class which wraps a Double:

```
class DoubleWrap( d : Double ) {
    def double( ) = d * 2
}
```

and an implicit conversion from Double to DoubleWrap:

```
implicit def wrapDouble( d : Double ) = new DoubleWrap( d )
```

This allows me to do the following:

```
scala> 2.5.double
res0: Double = 5.0
```

However, since there is an implicit conversion in Scala from Int to Double, I can also do the following:

```
scala> 2.double
res1: Double = 4.0
```

This operator can also be applied to all elements of a double-type collection using `map`

```
scala> List( 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 ).map( _.double )
res2: List[Double] = List(2.0, 4.0, 6.0)
```

However, if I attempt to apply the function to all elements of an integer collection, it doesn't work:

```
scala> List( 1, 2, 3 ).map( _.double )
<console>:10: error: value double is not a member of Int
          List( 1, 2, 3 ).map( _.double )
```

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: Strange, this worked in 2.8, you can try it e.g. at simplyscala.com.

Answer (score 3):

In scala, implicit conversions are **not** automatically chained. In other words, the compiler will look for a **single** implicit conversion that will allow the code to make sense, it will never try to apply two (or more) successive implicit conversions.

In your example, the fact that you can do `2.double` has nothing to do with the fact that there is an implicit conversion from `Double` to `Int` in `Predef`.
As a proof, try this in the REPL:

```
scala> val i: Int = 2
i: Int = 2

scala> i.double
<console>:13: error: value double is not a member of Int
              i.double
```

It does not compile.
So why does `2.double` compile? Good question. 
I thought I understood this intuitively: `2` can be interpreted as the `Int` value 2 or as the `Double` value 2.0 in the first place, so my intuition was that `2` is somehow already a `Double` in this context.
However, I think this is wrong, because even the following will compile, surpisingly: `(2:Int).double` (or even more strange: `((1+1):Int).double`). I'll be honest, I am flabbergasted and have no idea why this compiles while `val i: Int = 2; i.double` does not.

So to sum up, it is normal that scala does not try to apply two implicit conversions at the same time, but for some reason this rule does not seem to apply to **constant expressions**.

And now for a way to fix your issue: simply modify your implicit conversion so that it accepts any type that is itself implicitly convertible to `Double`. In effect, this allows to chain the implicit conversions:

```
implicit def wrapDouble[T <% Double]( d : T ) = new DoubleWrap( d )
```

Comment: I'd assumed that the answer was the command being interpreted as `(1.) double` - i.e. using a trailing . to indicate double and postfix method application. But your tests suggest this isn't the case (and there's no feature/deprecation warning, which there would be for my explanation). It's indeed baffling.

Comment: Yes, I thought about this possibility, but in fact (in scala 2.10) you can see that `2.double` compiles without warning, while `2.0 double` emits a warning saying that we should have imported `scala.language.postfixOps`. This shows quite clearly that the first version is not treated as a postfix operator, and thus the dot is not part of the literal.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7228) which should soon be [fixed](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2215).